# Cannot find BLE devices

Tags: java, android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am new to android application. I have made BLE scanner to detect BLE devices. I have used stopLeScan and startLeScan function to code it based on the tutorial i was following. however i cannot detect any BLE devices. while i was coding i found out that these functions are obsolete right now. is it because i have used obsolete function? or there is something else wrong in my code? if it is the obsolete function can you please tell me how to modify it so that is works?
FYI: i am running it on android pie.

I have went through android developer examples, different stackoverflow solutions. the tutorial i followed is stated below:
https://github.com/kaviles/BLE_Tutorials/tree/master/Android/01

this is my manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.ble_scanner">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.bluetooth_le" android:required="true"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

this is the mainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener, AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {

    private final static String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    public static final int REQUEST_ENABLE_BT = 1;

    private HashMap<String, BTLE_Device> mBTDevicesHashMap;
    private ArrayList<BTLE_Device> mBTDevicesArrayList;
    private ListAdapter_BTLE_Devices adapter;

    private Button btn_Scan;

    private BroadcastReceiver_BTState mBTStateUpdateReceiver;
    private Scanner_BTLE mBTLeScanner;

    private static final int LOCATION_REQUEST = 255;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if(!getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_BLUETOOTH_LE)){
            Utils.toast(getApplicationContext(),"BLE not supported");
            finish();
        }


        mBTStateUpdateReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver_BTState(getApplicationContext());
        mBTLeScanner = new Scanner_BTLE(this,15000,-150);

        mBTDevicesHashMap = new HashMap<>();
        mBTDevicesArrayList = new ArrayList<>();

        adapter = new ListAdapter_BTLE_Devices(this, R.layout.btle_device_list_item, mBTDevicesArrayList);

        ListView listView = new ListView(this);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(this);

        btn_Scan = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_scan);
        ((ScrollView)findViewById(R.id.device_list)).addView(listView);
        findViewById(R.id.btn_scan).setOnClickListener(this);
    }
    @Override
    protected void onStart(){
        super.onStart();

        registerReceiver(mBTStateUpdateReceiver, new IntentFilter(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_STATE_CHANGED));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume(){
        super.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause(){
        super.onPause();
        stopScan();
    }

    protected void onStop(){
        super.onStop();
        unregisterReceiver(mBTStateUpdateReceiver);
        stopScan();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy(){
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){

        if (requestCode == REQUEST_ENABLE_BT){
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK){
                Utils.toast(getApplicationContext(),"Bluetooth is ready to use");
            }
            else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED){
                Utils.toast(getApplicationContext(),"Please turn on Bluetooth");
            }
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
//        Context context = view.getContext();
//        stopScan();
//
//        String name = mBTDevicesArrayList.get(position).getName();
//        String address = mBTDevicesArrayList.get(position).getAddress();

    }
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()){
            case R.id.btn_scan:
                Utils.toast(getApplicationContext(),"Scan button pressed");

                if(!mBTLeScanner.isScanning()){
                    startScan();
                } else {
                    stopScan();
                }
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }

    }

    public void addDevice(BluetoothDevice device, int rssi) {

        String address = device.getAddress();
        if(!mBTDevicesHashMap.containsKey(address)){
            BTLE_Device btle_device = new BTLE_Device(device);
            btle_device.setRssi(rssi);

            mBTDevicesHashMap.put(address, btle_device);
            mBTDevicesArrayList.add(btle_device);
        } else {
            mBTDevicesHashMap.get(address).setRssi(rssi);
        }
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    }

    public void startScan(){
        btn_Scan.setText("Scanning...");

        mBTDevicesArrayList.clear();
        mBTDevicesHashMap.clear();

        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        mBTLeScanner.start();
    }

    public void stopScan() {
        btn_Scan.setText("Scan Again");

        mBTLeScanner.stop();
    }

    @TargetApi(23)
    private void verifyPermissionAndScan() {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) == PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            startScan();
        } else {
            requestPermissions(new String[] {ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION}, LOCATION_REQUEST);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult (int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
        if (requestCode != LOCATION_REQUEST) return;

        if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            startScan();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, R.string.location_permission_toast, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

}
```

this is the java class file with the adapter:

```
public class Scanner_BTLE {

    private MainActivity ma;

    private BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter;
    private boolean mScanning;
    private Handler mHandler;

    private long scanPeriod;
    private int signalStrength;

    public Scanner_BTLE(MainActivity mainActivity, long scanPeriod, int signalStrength) {
        ma = mainActivity;

        mHandler = new Handler();

        this.scanPeriod = scanPeriod;
        this.signalStrength = signalStrength;

        final BluetoothManager bluetoothManager = (BluetoothManager) ma.getSystemService(Context.BLUETOOTH_SERVICE);

        mBluetoothAdapter = bluetoothManager.getAdapter();
    }

    public boolean isScanning() {
        return mScanning;
    }

    public void start() {
        if (!Utils.checkBluetooth(mBluetoothAdapter)) {
            Utils.requestUserBluetooth(ma);
            ma.stopScan();
        } else {
            scanLeDevice(true);
        }
    }

    public void stop() {
        scanLeDevice(false);
    }

    private void scanLeDevice(final boolean enable) {
        if (enable && !mScanning) {
            Utils.toast(ma.getApplication(), "Starting BLE scan...");

            mHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Utils.toast(ma.getApplicationContext(), "Stopping BLE scan...");

                    mScanning = false;
                    mBluetoothAdapter.stopLeScan(mLeScanCallback);

                    ma.stopScan();
                }
            }, scanPeriod);
            mScanning = true;
            mBluetoothAdapter.startLeScan(mLeScanCallback);
        } else {
            mScanning = false;
            mBluetoothAdapter.stopLeScan(mLeScanCallback);
        }
    }

    private BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback mLeScanCallback =
            new BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onLeScan(final BluetoothDevice device, int rssi, byte[] scanRecord) {

                    final int new_rssi = rssi;
                    if (rssi > signalStrength) {
                        mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                ma.addDevice(device, new_rssi);
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }
            };

}
```

Rest of the files are as followed in the tutorial.

Here is my main XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingTop="20dp"
    android:paddingBottom="20dp"
    android:paddingLeft="20dp"
    android:paddingRight="20dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/device_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="515dp"
        android:fillViewport="true">

    </ScrollView>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_scan"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/start_scan" />

</LinearLayout>
```

This is my devicelist information XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="4"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:id="@+id/tv_name"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black" android:id="@+id/tv_rssi"/>

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:id="@+id/tv_macaddr"/>

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I don't see any error message. so i am kind of confused what to do and what i am doing wrong.

Comment: you never call `verifyPermissionAndScan()` in your code, that's why you will not find any device

Comment: should i call it in onCreate? how to call it?

Comment: onCreate should work

Comment: solved it. you were right. thank youvery much.